# Error: Realm context not found. Did you call useRealm() within a <RealmProvider/>?

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I am getting the following error when using useRealm() hook:

> ERROR  Error: Realm context not found.  Did you call useRealm() within a `<RealmProvider/>?`

Why am I getting this error and how to correct it?

I have followed the quickstart for React Native by Realm as described here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/quick-start/

Here is the source code.

App.jsx:

```
import TestView from './src/modules/sandbox/TestView';

function App() {
  return <TestView />;
}

export default App;
```

TestView.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import Realm from 'realm';
import { createRealmContext } from '@realm/react';
import TestComponent from './TestComponent';

// Define your object model
class Profile extends Realm.Object {
  static schema = {
    name: 'Profile',
    properties: {
      _id: 'objectId',
      name: 'string',
    },
    primaryKey: '_id',
  };
}

// Create a configuration object
const realmConfig = {
  schema: [Profile],
};

// Create a realm context
const { RealmProvider, useRealm, useObject, useQuery } = createRealmContext(realmConfig);

export default function TestView() {
  return (
    <RealmProvider>
      <TestComponent />
    </RealmProvider>
  );
}
```

TestComponent.jsx:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { useRealm } from '@realm/react';

export default function TestComponent() {
  const realm = useRealm();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Aloha</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
});
```

Realm and RN versions:

> ```
> "realm": "^11.10.1",
> "@realm/react": "^0.5.1",
> "react-native": "0.71.11",
> ```

Android 13:

[image]

iOS 16.4:

[image]

Comment: I don't see anywhere in that example code where they import the useRealm hook from the '@realm/react` package the way you're doing. That's a completely different package than the one that you are using to create your Realm (i.e. just the 'realm' package). My guess is it's using React's Context API, and you're trying to use a provider from one package with a consuming hook from another. I just had to solve a similar bug at work: my team puts out a provider and custom hook for next apps and another one for vanilla React and someone used the provider from one package with the hook from the other.

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks for your comment. Your guess does sound as a possible reason for the problem. I have opened issue on GitHub and realm dev gave me a solution, but he did not explain the reason. If you are interested in the conversation, read the conversationr below as answer or directly in the ticket https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/6013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have opened a ticket on GitHub related to this problem ( https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/6013 ). Long story short: the documentation is confusing and will be updated. Here is the conversation:

**@takemeyer:**

> @MinisX You must use the `useQuery` that was returned from `createRealmContext` in your application. Another option would be to omit `createRealmContext` and instead import the `RealmProvider` from `@realm/react` and implement it as so:
>
> ```
> <RealmProvider schemas={[Person]}>
> //...
> ```
>
> There is a default RealmContext already instantiated in `@realm/react`, so you only really need to call `createRealmContext` if you are creating multiple Realms. We will be updating the documentation soon to reflect this method if using Realm.

**@MinisX:**

> @takameyer Thanks for the response. Based on the documentation, `useQuery` and `useRealm` hooks have different uses. Therefore I do not quite understand your first suggestion.
>
> - > The useQuery() hook returns a collection of realm objects of a given type.
> - > The useRealm() hook returns the opened realm instance.
>
> https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/use-realm-react/
>
> I will give a try to your second suggestion today and give a feedback. But it does also cause confusion, as documentation says:
>
> - > Once you have wrapped your component with your RealmProvider, your component and its child components will have access to the useRealm(), useObject(), and useQuery() hooks.
>
> Your = something user has defined, not " instead import the RealmProvider from @realm/react ".

**@takemeyer:**

> @MinisX We are reworking that documentation right now to reduce confusion. I would recommend not using `createRealmContext` unless you need two different Realm databases (which is not common).
>
> Just import `RealmProvider` from `@realm/react` and use that for your application wrapper. Then you can use `useQuery`, `useRealm` and `useObject` hooks directly imported from `@realm/react` to have global access to your realm database.
>
> For example, in your wrapper:
>
> ```
> import { RealmProvider } from "@realm/react";
>  
>  export default function TestView() {
>    return (
>      <RealmProvider schemas={[Profile]}>
>        <TestComponent />
>      </RealmProvider>
>    );
>  }
> ```
>
> And in the children:
>
> ```
> import { useQuery } from "@realm/react";
>
> export function ProfileList() {
>   const profiles = useQuery(Profile);
>   //..render the result
> }
> ```

**@MinisX:**

> @takameyer this works, thank you for clarification!

Answer (score 0):

In your `TestComponent.jsx` class use the `useRealm` of
`const { RealmProvider, useRealm, useObject, useQuery } = createRealmContext(realmConfig);`
instead of `useRealm` which you imported from `import { useRealm } from '@realm/react';`.

Declare this `createRealmContext(realmConfig);` globally should be used in every class of application.